# Spring Repository for Vault secrets (v2)

Tags: spring, kotlin, repository, vault

I'm trying to resolve my vault stored credentials via a Spring Vault Repository. Unfortunately Spring assumes the wrong version number of the vault kv store (v1 instead of v2). I conclude this from the urls the repository fetches:

This is my @Secret entity:

```
@Secret("garmin-connect-credentials")
data class GarminConnectCredentials(
    @Id val id: String?,
    val fullName: String?,
    val email: String?,
    val password: String?,
)
```

This is my repository

```
@Repository
interface CredentialsRepository :
CrudRepository<GarminConnectCredentials, String>
```

and my properties:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      host: vault
      scheme: http
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: xxx-my-token-xxx
      kv:
        backend: secret
```

So when I try to resolve credentials via `credentialsRepository.findById("sullrich")`, the repository will fetch `http://vault:8200/v1/secret/garmin-connect-credentials/sullrich` to resolve the secret. This is wrong since the correct url should be `http://vault:8200/v1/secret/data/garmin-connect-credentials/sullrich`. The same goes for `credentialsRepository.findAll()` which fetches from `http://vault:8200/v1/secret/garmin-connect-credentials/?list=true` instead of `http://vault:8200/v1/secret/metadata/garmin-connect-credentials?list=true`

Any ideas on how to change this behaviour?